# WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied while installing statsmodels using Canopy

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, statsmodels, canopy

I am a complete newbie to python. I recently installed Canopy and then installed package xlrd successfully. However, I tried installing statsmodel and scikit_learn using the package manager. This is the errorlog from when I try to install.

Warming up...

```
Fetching: intel_runtime-14.0.6.241-1.egg (4.63 MB)
[................................................................................]

Fetching: MKL-2017.0.1-1.egg (139.55 MB)
[................................................................................]

Fetching: numpy-1.10.4-4.egg (3.40 MB)
[................................................................................]

Fetching: scipy-0.17.1-3.egg (12.72 MB)
[................................................................................]

Fetching: setuptools-23.1.0-2.egg (681 KB)
[................................................................................]

Fetching: patsy-0.4.1-2.egg (474 KB)
[................................................................................]

Fetching: pandas-0.19.0-1.egg (9.57 MB)
[................................................................................]

Fetching: statsmodels-0.6.1-18.egg (5.98 MB)
[................................................................................]

Removing egg: pandas-0.18.0-8.egg (24.96 MB)
[................................................................................]

Removing egg: setuptools-23.1.0-1.egg (1.74 MB)
[................................................................................]

Removing egg: scipy-0.17.1-1.egg (37.65 MB)
[................................................................................]

Removing egg: numpy-1.10.4-1.egg (11.98 MB)
[................................................................................]

Removing egg: MKL-11.1.4-1.egg (230.83 MB)
[................................................................................]

Installing egg: intel_runtime-14.0.6.241-1.egg (13.36 MB)
[................................................................................]

Installing egg: MKL-2017.0.1-1.egg (389.41 MB)
[................................................................................]

Installing egg: MKL-2017.0.1-1.egg (389.41 MB)
[................................................................................]
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File
>   "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_dashboard\packman\package_action_worker.py",
>   line 54, in run   File
>   "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_dashboard\packman\package_action.py",
>   line 193, in execute   File
>   "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_dashboard\packman\packman.py", line
>   346, in    File
>   "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_dashboard\packman\packman.py", line
>   893, in _install   File
>   "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_platform\cpython_packages_manager.py",
>   line 102, in install_package PackageInstallationError: installation of
>   package statsmodels 0.6.1-18 failed. Details below:    stdout: 
>   stderr:  exception: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_platform\assets\enpkg_slave.py",
>   line 358, in main   File
>   "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_platform\assets\enpkg_slave.py",
>   line 84, in install_package   File
>   "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\canopy_platform\assets\enpkg_slave.py",
>   line 96, in install_packages   File
>   "F:\Udemy\canopy\Workspace\User\lib\site-packages\enstaller\cli\utils.py",
>   line 179, in install_req
>       enpkg.execute(actions)   File "F:\Udemy\canopy\Workspace\User\lib\site-packages\enstaller\enpkg.py",
>   line 350, in execute
>       action.execute()   File "F:\Udemy\canopy\Workspace\User\lib\site-packages\enstaller\enpkg.py",
>   line 149, in execute
>       for currently_extracted_size in self.iter_execute():   File "F:\Udemy\canopy\Workspace\User\lib\site-packages\enstaller\enpkg.py",
>   line 143, in iter_execute
>       for step in installer.install_iterator(extra_info):   File "F:\Udemy\canopy\Workspace\User\lib\site-packages\egginst\main.py",
>   line 461, in install_iterator
>       n = self._extract(arcname, is_custom_egg)   File "F:\Udemy\canopy\Workspace\User\lib\site-packages\egginst\main.py",
>   line 479, in _extract
>       self._write_arcname(name)   File "F:\Udemy\canopy\Workspace\User\lib\site-packages\egginst\main.py",
>   line 557, in _write_arcname
>       self.z.extract_to(arcname, destination, self.prefix)   File "F:\Udemy\canopy\Workspace\User\lib\site-packages\egginst_zipfile.py",
>   line 35, in extract_to
>       return self._extract_member_to(member, destination, path, pwd)   File
>   "F:\Udemy\canopy\Workspace\User\lib\site-packages\egginst_zipfile.py",
>   line 96, in _extract_member_to
>       _unlink_if_exists(targetpath)   File "F:\Udemy\canopy\Workspace\User\lib\site-packages\egginst_zipfile.py",
>   line 113, in _unlink_if_exists
>       os.unlink(p) WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'F:\Udemy\canopy\Workspace\User\Scripts\mk2iomp5md.dll'

I have tried running Canopy in Admin mode, also used the command "python -m pip install statsmodels" from the command prompt but that didn't help either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the trouble. Windows sometimes holds locks on library files, interfering with package installation. Canopy 2.0 (January) will guard against this better. Meanwhile, please reboot Windows, then open a Canopy Command Prompt from the start menu (do not open Canopy itself), and type the following command:

`enpkg statsmodels`

Comment: Hi Jonathan, Thank you for your reply. I followed your steps and seems like it worked. However, I am a newbie to python and I am not sure how can I check in canopy whether statsmodels and scikit-learn have been installed? Is there a command or something that I can go and check on Canopy UI?

Comment: a) The package manager should show the packages as installed.

Comment: b) You should be able to import the packages in the Python panel of the Canopy GUI.

`import statsmodels`

Comment: Thank you so much Jonathan. I really appreciate it!!